# sql join with foreign key table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select all users from my database with emails ending `@gmail.com` which are not already in the group with the `groupID` 4.

The problem is my `user_to_group` table looks like this:

```
userID | groupID
--------------------
1      | 5
1      | 4
1      | 3
2      | 3
2      | 6
```

Users with the `groupID` 4 are excluded, but because they are also in other groups, they will be selected anyway. In this example I just need the user with the `userID` 2.

Is it possible to exclude users which are in group 4 regardless of their other groups?

```
SELECT * FROM wcf13_user user_table
RIGHT JOIN wcf13_user_to_group ON (wcf13_user_to_group.userID = user_table.userID && groupID != 4 )
WHERE user_table.email LIKE "%@gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with an `EXISTS` subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM wcf13_user user_table u
WHERE user_table.email LIKE "%@gmail.com" -- Has a gmail account
  AND NOT EXISTS (                        -- Is not a member of group #4
       SELECT *
       FROM wcf13_user_to_group g
       WHERE u.userID=g.userID AND groupID = 4
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a good place to use the `not exists` clause:

```
SELECT ut.*
FROM wcf13_user ut 
WHERE not exists (select 1
                  from wcf13_user_to_group utg
                  where utg.userID = ut.userID and utggroupID = 4
                 ) and
      ut.email LIKE '%@gmail.com';
```